# FS2 Stream with StateT[IO, _, _], periodically dumping state

Tags: scala, monad-transformers, scala-cats, fs2, cats-effect

I have a program which consumes an infinite stream of data. Along the way I'd like to record some metrics, which form a monoid since they're just simple sums and averages. Periodically, I want to write out these metrics somewhere, clear them, and return to accumulating them. I have essentially:

```
object Foo {
  type MetricsIO[A] = StateT[IO, MetricData, A]

  def recordMetric(m: MetricData): MetricsIO[Unit] = {
    StateT.modify(_.combine(m))
  }

  def sendMetrics: MetricsIO[Unit] = {
    StateT.modifyF { s =>
      val write: IO[Unit] = writeMetrics(s)
      write.attempt.map {
        case Left(_) => s
        case Right(_) => Monoid[MetricData].empty
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So most of the execution uses `IO` directly and lifts using `StateT.liftF`. And in certain situations, I include some calls to `recordMetric`. At the end of it I've got a stream:

```
val mainStream: Stream[MetricsIO, Bar] = ...
```

And I want to periodically, say every minute or so, dump the metrics, so I tried:

```
val scheduler: Scheduler = ...
val sendStream =
  scheduler
    .awakeEvery[MetricsIO](FiniteDuration(1, TimeUnit.Minutes))
    .evalMap(_ => Foo.sendMetrics)

val result = mainStream.concurrently(sendStream).compile.drain
```

And then I do the usual top level program stuff of calling `run` with the start state and then calling `unsafeRunSync`.

The issue is, I only ever see empty metrics! I suspect it's something to with my monoid implicitly providing empty metrics to `sendStream` but I can't quite figure out why that should be or how to fix it. Maybe there's a way I can "interleave" these `sendMetrics` calls into the main stream instead?

Edit: here's a **minimal complete runnable example**:

```
import fs2._
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data._
import cats.effect._
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val sec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4)
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(sec)

type F[A] = StateT[IO, List[String], A]

val slowInts = Stream.unfoldEval[F, Int, Int](1) { n =>
  StateT(state => IO {
    Thread.sleep(500)
    val message = s"hello $n"
    val newState = message :: state
    val result = Some((n, n + 1))
    (newState, result)
  })
}

val ticks = Scheduler.fromScheduledExecutorService(sec).fixedDelay[F](FiniteDuration(1, SECONDS))

val slowIntsPeriodicallyClearedState = slowInts.either(ticks).evalMap[Int] {
  case Left(n) => StateT.liftF(IO(n))
  case Right(_) => StateT(state => IO {
    println(state)
    (List.empty, -1)
  })
}
```

Now if I do:

```
slowInts.take(10).compile.drain.run(List.empty).unsafeRunSync
```

Then I get the expected result - the state properly accumulates into the output. But if I do:

```
slowIntsPeriodicallyClearedState.take(10).compile.drain.run(List.empty).unsafeRunSync
```

Then I see an empty list consistently printed out. I would have expected partial lists (approx. 2 elements) printed out.

Answer (score 3):

`StateT` is not safe to use with effect types, because it's not safe in the face of concurrent access. Instead, consider using a `Ref` (from either fs2 or cats-effect, depending what version).

Something like this:

```
def slowInts(ref: Ref[IO, Int]) = Stream.unfoldEval[F, Int, Int](1) { n =>
  val message = s"hello $n"
  ref.modify(message :: _) *> IO {
    Thread.sleep(500)
    val result = Some((n, n + 1))
    result
  }
}

val ticks = Scheduler.fromScheduledExecutorService(sec).fixedDelay[IO](FiniteDuration(1, SECONDS))

def slowIntsPeriodicallyClearedState(ref: Ref[IO, Int] = 
  slowInts.either(ticks).evalMap[Int] {
    case Left(n) => IO.pure(n)
    case Right(_) =>
      ref.modify(_ => Nil).flatMap { case Change(previous, now) => 
        IO(println(now)).as(-1)
      }
  }
```